# Data Formatting not retained when exporting to .xls

Tags: c#, devexpress, export-to-excel, xtrareport

I'm using XtraReports, I'm having issues when exporting report to `.xls`

Some of my data needs formatting before being displayed to browser.

```
private void xrTableCell1_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
   xrTableCell1.Text = "(" + xrTableCell1.Text + ")";
}
```

to format my data before printing, I use the code above. But when exporting data to `.xls`, the appended `"("` and `")"` are removed.

I happen to see that it is occuring when I'm using the following code:

```
xrTableCell1.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSource, "ClassPropertyName");
```

But is not occurring when i simply use:

```
xrTableCell1.Text = "My Data";
```

The thing is, I cannot use `.Text` for I'm binding multiple rows of data. Why is that happening? Is there a solution/alternative for this? Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to fix this issue. Just after the `CreateDocument()` method, add this line of code:

```
ReportViewer.Report.ExportOptions.Xls.TextExportMode = TextExportMode.Text;
```